# How to solve Directory nonexistent error on building docker image?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Given a `Dockerfile` with the content below:

```
FROM sauloefo/my-ubuntu-22.04:v1

RUN git clone https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf.git ~/.asdf --branch v0.10.2

RUN echo 'source ~/.asdf/asdf.fish' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish
```

The following error is happening on `docker build` call:

```bash
 > [3/3] RUN echo 'source ~/.asdf/asdf.fish' >> ~/.config/fish/config.fish:
#6 0.372 /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /root/.config/fish/config.fish: Directory nonexistent
```

But if I create a container directly from the base image (`sauloefo/my-ubuntu-22.04:v1`) the file exists.

Does anybody know what am I missing?

Comment: How are you creating this container? When I do it, I get an error `Aborted (core dumped)`.

Comment: I'm creating the container using `docker run --interactive --tty --rm --name dev-env sauloefo/my-ubuntu-22.04:v1`

Comment: What tool are you actually trying to install via `asdf`; can you use that directly, or maybe even use a prebuilt image containing it?  Version-management tools like `asdf` tend to not work well in Docker.  In your particular case, you're going to run into the three problems that (1) "home directory" isn't a well-defined concept in Docker; (2) most paths to running Docker containers don't read shell dotfiles; and (3) `source` isn't a standard shell command.

Comment: Regardless what I am going to use `asdf` for, I'm bothered about why a file created in the base image is not available during the image build. I believe there is some fundamental Docker concept I am missing here.
But just to answer your question I will use `asdf` to manage `nodejs` different versions.